# Repopulate DataGridView on CellEndEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to update a value in the database after the user finishes editing a cell. The DataGridView is populated manually (and dynamically) due to some complexities involved in DataBinding this particular data set.

In the event handler for `CellEndEdit`, I have called my method to update the value back to the database, and it works as planned. The trouble occurs when I attempt to repopulate the DataGridView. For reference, this method is called `PopulateAccounts()`.

Once a value is entered in the cell, everything works perfectly if the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> on their keyboard or clicks another control on the form. However, clicking on another cell in the same DataGridView results in the following error:

> Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.

The `PopulateAccounts()` method includes `DataGridView.Rows.Clear()` which throws the error. I've researched this error in a few related SO questions, and it seems to be related to threading, which I'm clueless about. One suggested fix is to invoke my `PopulateAccounts()` method:

```
BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(PopulateAccounts));
```

This works, but it causes the DataGridView to select all cells preceding the one that was edited (see screenshot below)

[image: faultyDGV]

Again, this **only** happens when clicking out of the cell and into another. Otherwise, i.e. pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or clicking on another control, it simply selects the first cell.

Here is the code for PopulateAccounts() for reference:

```
    // Populates the DataGridView's account records.
    private void PopulateAccounts()
    {
        dgvShed.Rows.Clear();

        using (PassShedEntities context = new PassShedEntities(conString))
        {
            foreach (Account acct in context.Account.Where(a => a.Category_id == (int)lstCategories.SelectedValue))
            {
                dgvShed.Rows.Add();

                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvShed.Columns)
                {
                    Credential cred = (from c in context.Credential
                                       join f in context.Field on c.Field_id equals f.Id
                                       join a in context.Account on c.Account_id equals a.Id
                                       where c.Account_id == acct.Id
                                       where f.Label == col.Name
                                       select c).SingleOrDefault();

                    dgvShed.Rows[dgvShed.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[col.Name].Tag = cred.Id;
                    dgvShed.Rows[dgvShed.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[col.Name].Value = cred.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the PopulateAccounts code in your post?

Comment: Done. The dgvShed.Rows.Clear() method throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

*Once a value is entered in the cell, everything works perfectly if the user presses Enter on their keyboard or clicks another control on the form*

The above actions doesn't change the `CurrentCell` and the grid repopulation works fine.

*However, clicking on another cell in the same DataGridView results in the following error:*

When you click on another cell the `CurrentCell` of the datagridview is changing and  grid internally calls the `SetCurrentCellAddressCore` to do the cell change. This call internally raises `CellEndEdit` event which triggers the `SetCurrentCellAddressCore` again and this cycle goes on resulting in infinite loop. The `DataGridView` detects this loop and throws exception resulting in the error you have mentioned.

In the above case the my guess is that `DataGridView` somehow goofed up the selection of cells. You could simply clear the selection at the end of `PopulateAccounts` with `DataGridView.ClearSelection()` method.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I had tried using ClearSelection() after the PopulateAccounts() method, and it simply has no effect.

Since the CellEndEdit updates the database, I realized that I don't necessarily need to repopulate the DataGridView in this event handler since the cell already contains the exact same value as the database (it's just technically not bound to the database). 

So, unless someone knows a way to fix the cell selection issue for general knowledge, it's no longer an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrestling with just about the exact same problem and just came up with a solution that works with my specifics.  I moved all the code from the CellEndEdit event to the CellValueChanged event (which fires right before the former) and now both options for ending the cell-edit: the enter-stroke and clicking off to another cell, work great.

I'm not sure what the perfectly proper way to use the events is, but this seems to be working!